# How to understand "slug" as part of a web URL?

Tags: meaning, word-meaning

How to understand "slug" as part of a web URL?

When I look for "slug" in a dictionary, this is what I get:

1. [image: an animal slug]
2. [image: a metal slug]

How to understand the relationship between "URL slug" and the meanings below?

I found a blog page [What is a URL Slug & How to Use Them Successfully in Your SEO Strategy?](https://rockcontent.com/blog/what-is-url-slug/), this may be helpful.

Comment: The animal name in the first picture derives from ***slug** = A slow, lazy fellow; a sluggard*, first attested by the full OED 1425. They have a separate entry for the sense *A piece of lead or other metal for firing from a gun; a roughly-formed bullet*, first attested 1622, which they think *might* derive from the first definition (but they don't *know*). The OED don't explicitly list your second sense, but I assume it's by extension from that second "lump of metal" sense.

Comment: [...here are written instances](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22locking+slug%22) of the collocation ***locking slug***, which are "similar" to your second pic. The bit at the end of a URL is a figurative "locating pin / locking slug" that nails the URL to a ***specific page / position*** within a website. Note - this is all guesswork on my part, since the full OED has ***no relevant definitions*** for even the "locating pin" sense (which I just happen to be familiar with), let alone the URL usage!

Comment: This is probably a Webmasters SE or English SE question. It's technical jargon, not regular usage.

Comment: Typesetters used to have 'slugs' didn't they?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: That's the full OED's definition 4b (Printing) *A metal bar used as a division, or one produced by a Linotype machine for printing from.* Originally U.S. *Hence **slug-machine**, a Linotype machine.* Basically, that "division bar" is another "locking / positioning bar" usage as per my comment.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - in typesetting a slug could be something generic or prepared for frequent use, such as lines of type for the printer's or binder's benefit, e.g. the name of the printer, the item or job number, and the telephone number of the printer, etc.  Wikipedia says: _This term is also used in web publishing to refer to short article labels that may be used as part of a URL. Slugs are usually derived from an article's title and are limited in length, and to a specific set of characters (to prevent percent-encoding); often only letters, numbers, and hyphens are allowed._

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: Yes, but all such usages are trivially derived from the *piece of lead* original in my first comment. Which as I said, I think eventually leads to the modern URL sense through the use of "positioning" pins / rods.

Comment: I am probably not the only person who has no idea what a "URL slug" is, or where and how it is used. I feel you should give more details about the use of "URL slug"  that you found, because without context, we could be talking about a typo.

Comment: The word 'slug' is used in lots of different contexts for lots of different things. The reference is usually to the slug-like shape of whatever the thing happens to be. I don't know if that is the case with a URL slug, but I suspect it might be.

Comment: Having found out exactly what a URL slug is, I might guess the reference could be to a "token" (a slug is also another word for one of those coins you get in an amusement arcade), to a bullet (itself often called a "slug" because of the shape of some sorts of bullet) in reference to its small size and high importance, or to a semi-processed piece of metal that's destined to further shaped further down the production line. And if anyone objects that I've effectively covered every definition in the dictionary for slug, then they'd be right! ;-)

Comment: Usage in web publishing
Main article: Slug (web publishing)
This term is also used in web publishing to refer to short article labels that may be used as part of a URL. Slugs are usually derived from an article's title and are limited in length, and to a specific set of characters (to prevent percent-encoding); often only letters, numbers, and hyphens are allowed.[2] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slug_(typesetting)

Comment: @Jaime
 There are other senses of 'slug" as well. Fopr one thjing, a "slug" is is a unit of Mas in the foot-pound-second (engl;ish) system. An object that weighs 32 pounds in a 1 G field has a mass of 1 slug. It is also a quantity of drink ingested in a single gulp. There are other senses as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Wikipedia<sup>*</sup> claims](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clean_URL#Slug) its usage is derived from [(offline) publishing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slug_(publishing)):

> In newspaper editing, a slug is a short name given to an article that is in production. The story is labeled with its slug as it makes its way from the reporter through the editorial process.
>
> ...
>
> > The origin of the term slug derives from the days of hot-metal printing, when printers set type by hand in a small form called a stick. Later huge Linotype machines turned molten lead into casts of letters, lines, sentences and paragraphs. A line of lead in both eras was known as a slug.

That matches one of the [dictionary definitions in Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/slug):

> 6 a : a strip of metal thicker than a printer's lead
>    b : a line of type cast as one piece
>    c : a usually temporary type line serving to instruct or identify

<sup>*</sup>: hey, we're mentioned there :)